# I have written this Python code to make HTTP Post to NLP and then save the result

Tags: python, google-api, nlp, http-post

This is working fine when paste the content individually.
However, I many text files to read. Need help on how can I make it to read content from text files and then save the result.

```py
import requests
    
url = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:annotateText?key=***************'
myobj = {
    "document": {
        "type": 1,"language": "EN",
        "content": "INSERT TEXT HERE"
    },
    "features": {
        "extractSyntax": "FALSE",
        "extractEntities": "TRUE",
        "extractDocumentSentiment": "FALSE",
        "extractEntitySentiment": "FALSE",
        "classifyText": "TRUE"
    }
}
    
def hitGoogleAPI(url, myobj):
    req = requests.post(url,json=myobj)
    response= req.text
    print(response)
    
hitGoogleAPI(url, myobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `bs4` library to parse and save the response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def hitGoogleAPI(url, myobj):
    req = requests.post(url,json=myobj)
    response= req.text
    save_it_as_html = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser") # or you could other types of parsers instead of using "html.parser" 
    print(save_it_as_html)
```